# Display google analytics data on my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics

i want to display Google analytic data like page view, events and ...
i found Google analytic dashboard controls  but it doesn't work, can anyone tell me is there any component file that gets Google analytic data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Analytics Super Proxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy) to display your GA data on your website.